# is_account_page() change to page slug

Tags: functions, pages, page-template, slug

i'm really new to wordpress php. which function should i use to replace is_account_page() in a code. here's what I'm trying to achieve
before

```
if (is_account_page()){
do some code here
}
```

after

```
if (user on this page slug){
do some code here
}
```

what is the appropriate function I should use for the **user on this page slug** part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the is_page() function - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

The function signature accepts one parameter - $page

> (int|string|int[]|string[]) (Optional) Page ID, title, slug, or array
> of such to check against.

Default value: ''

```php
if ( is_page('account') ){
   // do some code here
}
```